# Laravel project isnt working after git clone

Tags: php, git, laravel

So I started a new project and I downloaded clone of it, I did composer install & update. And I do php artisan serve to start, but there is a error says in server.php :

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public_html/index.php';
```

> Warning:
>   require_once(C:\Users\eless\PhpstormProjects\vigil/public_html/index.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\eless\PhpstormProjects\vigil\server.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\Users\eless\PhpstormProjects\vigil/public_html/index.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\Users\eless\PhpstormProjects\vigil\server.php on line 21

then I change it to /public instead of /public_html then its just a white screen and made php artisan migration(there was some errors about table but) says

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong

project is not visible. What I should do? Is anyone can help?

Comment: make sure you have .env file in your project root

Comment: yeah I do have it, but there is no APP_KEY other parts I added like database, etc

Comment: Also once your .env is in there, run `php artisan key:gen` and your storage permissions may need altering.

Comment: OK now I did it. also name of .env file was something else I changed it, now It gives database error so I will check it out.

Comment: What error is it now giving? This is a different question to be honest..

Comment: OK option just write your explanations about .env and generate key as answer of these subject, this was a answer.

Comment: I have added an answer for you along with the possible solution to your database error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename .env.example to .env and then run `php artisan key:gen` to provide an APP_KEY within the .env file.

Edit your database config settings accordingly... (username, password etc)

Once this is done, run `php artisan migrate` to move your database migrations into the database you set up and then reload your browser.